# Как создать видео streaming?

Tags: веб-программирование, видео

Добрый день.
Есть необходимость создать возможность потокового видео (streaming).
Проект типа web cam online. Понятия не имею с чего начать, и в какую сторону копать. ((
Благодарен всем за ответы.

Comment: PHP (@)_(@)

Нет, точно не на пхп)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, вам понадобится:

- Флэшка (swf) с подключением камеры и посылкой сигнала (в AS3 это есть)
- RTMP-сервер (прямо так вбивайте в гугл, + есть несколько забугорных сервисов)
- Сайт, на котором вы это разместите

Сразу говорю, сервис довольно дорого вам обойдется, даже если "все сами" - сервер ртмп должен быть довольно мощный даже для 10-20 потоков.

По самому RTMP, протоколу, серверам и софту много есть на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/tag/rtmp/)

[гугл 1](http://www.google.ru/search?q=RTMP%20хостинг)

[гугл 2](http://www.google.ru/search?q=RTMP%20протокол)

[класс Camera на адоб.ком](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html)

Comment: вроде слышал что red5 сервер используют.. или ошибаюсь ?

Comment: И его тоже, ага. Я вроде на нем и ставил (точнее, мне ставили, брали сервер у пендосов с платной установкой).

Answer (score 0):

FMS - flash media server, решение от адобщииков, платное.